# How can I get the "indexOf" an element in a <p>? (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to get the index position of tagged elements(marks) inside a paragraph.
ex:

```
<p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor ipsum sit <mark>amet</mark>
   consectetur adipisicing elit, sed <mark>amet</mark> 
</p>
```

I'm trying to emulate the "**ctrl+f**" function in a div. So im using a plugin called **textselect** to select/highlight 
my search result with this:

```
var startPosition = textHolder.indexOf(textToSelect);
var endPosition = startPosition + textToSelect.length;

$.textSelect('setRange', {
                        start: startPosition,
                        startElement: $("p"),
                        end : endPosition,
                        endElement : $("p")
                    });
```

but i don't know how can i get the **startposition**...

I tried this:

```
var textHolder = $('div').find('p').contents("mark").eq(0);

$('div').find('p').html().indexOf(textHolder.html())
```

and returns 34 this would be the startposition of the first mark but if  change the textholder to `.eq(1)` returns 34 again. How can I get the **indexOf** of each mark substring?

Comment: what do you mean by index position. you need to hit the edit button and rewrite the question without assuming everyone can read your mind.

Comment: Are you asking for the character counts leading up to each element? Would the spaces after `<p>` count? Would `<mark>amet</mark>` count as 17 characters (when calculating the index of the second `mark`), or just 4? What *specific* results would you expect from the example above, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding an id to your paragraph as well as to your 'marked' tags and then obtaining your text as a variable like so:

```
var paragraph = document.getElementById("paragraph_id").innerHTML;
```

You can then get the starting positions of your substrings using this:

```
var n1 = paragraph.indexOf('<marked id="m1">');
var n2 = paragraph.indexOf('<marked id="m2">');
```

If you need to get your ending indexes, you can save other strings from your 'marked' tags similar as described before and add the `m1_string_name.length` property to your n1 value and `m2_string_name.length` property to your n2 value.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is basically what you are looking for:

```
var paragraph = $("#paragraph").html();
var startIndex = paragraph.indexOf("<mark>");
var endIndex = paragraph.indexOf("</mark>");
```

If you want to do this dynamically just put it within a loop a substring from the endIndex each time. Something like this:

```
var paragraph = $("#paragraph").html();
var lastIndexFound = false;
while(!lastIndexFound)
{
    var startPostition = paragraph.indexOf("<mark>");
    var endPosition = paragraph.indexOf("</mark>");
    if (endPosition == -1)
    {
        lastIndexFound = true;
        break;
    }
    $.textSelect('setRange', {
                    start: startPosition,
                    startElement: $("p"),
                    end : endPosition,
                    endElement : $("p")
                });
    paragraph = paragraph.substring(endPosition, paragraph.length);

}
```

Comment: Basically. But I need to do it for each <mark> element in order to get the position of each mark

Comment: I have updated the answer with code to iterate through the paragraph, granted i haven't tested it it may need slight modification.